# FakeItEasy - faking setter behaviour to store a value and then getter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

Ultimately I want to have an internal interface with a setter and a public one with a getter. The code that replicates this scenario is roughed below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        var fake1 = A.Fake<IInterface1>(a => a.Implements(typeof(IInterface2)));

        string backingString = null;

        IInterface2 fake2 = (IInterface2)fake1;
        A.CallTo(fake1)
            .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("set_Property"))
            .Invokes((string param) => { backingString = param; });
        A.CallTo(fake1)
            .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("get_Property"))
            .WithReturnType<string>().Returns(backingString); //doesn't work

        A.CallTo(fake2)
            .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("set_Property"))
            .Invokes((string param) => { backingString = param; });
        A.CallTo(fake2)
            .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("get_Property"))
            .WithReturnType<string>().Returns(backingString); //doesn't work

        fake1.Property = "asdf";


        Assert.AreEqual("asdf", fake1.Property); //fails -> fake1.Property is null
        Assert.AreEqual(fake1.Property, fake2.Property); //fails -> fake2.Property is null
    }
}

public interface IInterface1
{
    string Property { get; set; }
}

public interface IInterface2
{
    string Property { get; }
}
```

I could get as far as using `backingString` to store the setter, but when setting up the getter it doesn't work as I wanted it to.

I also tried something in the line of `A.CallTo(() => fake1.Property).Returns(backingString)` to no avail.

Would appreciate assistance of them experts :)

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to create a fake that returns a specific value when its property getter is invoked?

Comment: @YacoubMassad The point was to get around [this "issue"|http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405776/fakeiteasy-problems-with-new-modifier]. Essentially I wanted to have the fake object behave like a real object when implementing two interfaces with a property with the same name. Regardless of its polymorphic shape it should return the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up your

```
A.CallTo(fake1)
    .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("get_Property"))
    .WithReturnType<string>().Returns(backingString);
```

(and similarly for `fake2`),

the value of `backingString` is `null`, so that's what's returned later on when you access the `Property` getter.

In order to return the value of `backingString` *at the time the `Property` getter is called*, you want [ReturnsLazily](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-return-values/#return-values-calculated-at-call-time).

Make this change in each place and the tests pass:

```
A.CallTo(fake1)
    .Where(a => a.Method.Name.Equals("get_Property"))
    .WithReturnType<string>().ReturnsLazily(() => backingString);
```

Comment: Gosh, I can't believe I missed this. Could've sworn I tried returns lazily. It was a long day yesterday. Thanks again Blair